# Laravel | Inject into Controller from middleware

Tags: php, laravel

This is more of a question of how to do something in regards to best practices.

I have a website which is going to host multiple 'stores'. The stores will all be run from a subdomain, for example `store1.example.com`. This store name will determine what `store_id` to look for in the database.

I know in the middleware, I can get the store and I can resolve the store. However, is their a way to do something like this within the controller....

```
public function getProducts(Store $store, $slug) {
    $product = Product::query()->where('store_id', $store->id)->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
}
```

I am relativaly new to Laravel which is why I'm asking for an opinion on what you guys think is best to do.

The whole reason for this is because I want to be able to do `store1.example.com/product-1` but obviously the page will have stuff related to the store which we get from the sub domain.

Maybe I've gone completely off track here and there is a better way on doing it.

Let me know!

UPDATE:

So I did actually manage to get this work...

```php
class SubDomain {
    public function handle($request, Closure $closure, $guard = null) 
    {
        app()->bind(Store::class, function () {
            return Store::query()->where('id', 1)->firstOrFail();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Comment: But does that resolve the actual store from the subdomain?

Comment: If you define a store model you can use [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding)